# Как спозиционировать стрелочки в слайдере?

Tags: css

Как cпозиционировать стрелочки в слайдере так, чтобы они сохраняли пропорции своего расположения при изменении размера окна браузера?

Пробовал использовать процент в селекторе `top`, не работает (

```css
* {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.arrow-left {
  position: relative;
  top: 12em;
  left: 10%;
  background: blue;
}

.arrow-right {
  position: relative;
  top: 12em;
  left: 90%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <label for="r5" class="arrow-left">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
      </label>
      <label for="r2" class="arrow-right">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </label>
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="s1 slide active">
          <img src="images/Main_image.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="s2 slide">
          <img src="images/Main_image_2.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="s3 slide">
          <img src="images/Main_image_3.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: А теперь, глянь со стороны на свою верстку, и объясни, где должны располагаться  кнопки....

Comment: @Air В div.slideshow. А что здесь не так?

Comment: Я же не сказал, что в верстке, что-то  не так...  Не понятно каков должен быть конечный результат...  Что именно не получается?

Comment: @Air Нужны стрелочки-контроллеры по бокам слайдера. Проблема, в том, что нужно чтобы они были адаптивны под размер экрана. Медиа не хочется делать. Не могу понять, как их правильно разместить и застилизовать, чтобы они были эластичными. https://paste.pics/76099bb6c2fb25231f31358930cf7a46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По аналогу `transform: translateY(-50%);` Можно выровнять и по оси ***X***  `transform: translateX(N%);`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 1px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

* {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.arrow-left {
  left: 10%;
  background: blue;
}

.arrow-right {
  left: 90%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <label for="r5" class="arrow-left">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                </label>
      <label for="r2" class="arrow-right">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </label>
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="s1 slide active">
          <img src="images/Main_image.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="s2 slide">
          <img src="images/Main_image_2.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="s3 slide">
          <img src="images/Main_image_3.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все получилось! Я так понял, секрет в transform: translate?

Comment: А не подскажешь, почему у меня не работало top: 50%? Я при этом делал без translate. Дело в translate?

Comment: `top:50%;` - позиционирует относительно верхнего края родителя, а `transform: translateY(-50%);`  сдвигает по оси `Y`  отталкиваясь от высоты блока (дочернего элемента), таким образом мы получаем самый универсальный вариант центрировать блок

Comment: Блок дочернего элемента - это какой в данном случае?

Comment: `<div class="slideshow">` - ***parentElement***   `<label for="r5" class="arrow-left">` - ***childElement***

Comment: Ок. Понял. Еще попрактикуюсь с translate. Спасибо

Comment: всегда пожалуйста