# Центрирование svg в контейнере

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Каким образом возможно центрировать svg в родительском div, если неизвестны заранее размеры самой svg? Она формируется по данным, приходящим с api.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как спозиционировать стрелочки в слайдере?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1028070/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Comment: Как и любой другой элемент...  Пройди по ссылке посмотри ответ...

Comment: А еще существуют `flex && grid`

Answer (score 0):

Задайте родительскому:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Либо оберните ваш svg в div, которому задайте фиксированную ширину, а svg внутри добавьте свойство **max-width: 100%**.